# How do I configure android tests directory?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

The Android gradle build forces my AndroidTests to be in src/androidTests. How do I change this to be another directory of my choosing?

Here is some background:
I am migrating a project from eclipse.

According to the build documentation, when I add this to my gradle build file:

```
androidTest.setRoot('tests')
```

The android gradle build does this:
"Note: setRoot() moves the whole sourceSet (and its sub folders) to a new folder. This moves src/androidTest/* to tests/*"

That is great for the build and makes it run just fine.

However, it forces my project structure to put my androidTests within: src/AndroidTest. This makes Eclipse unable to compile because it thinks all the test code should be in a package called androidTests.com.etc.etc.etc...

I'd like to set some property like this:

> ```
> androidTest
> {
>     java.srcDirs = ['tests']
> }
> ```

Answer (score 15):

`androidTest.setRoot('tests')` will reset the root of the sourceSets so that

- java is under `tests/java`
- android res are under `tests/res`
- etc...

You can configure those separately though with

```
android {
  sourceSets {
    androidTest {
      java.srcDirs = ['tests']
    }
  }
}
```

Note: this uses `android.sourceSets` because the Android plugin uses custom sourceSets.

Comment: I'm getting picky now, but is there any way to change the source directory to be just "tests" instead of tests/java?

Comment: This is what the code above does. It's saying that your java folder for the tests is `tests`.

Answer (score 3):

There are slight variations on how to do this. Putting the following in my build.gradle file worked for me:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest{
            java.srcDir file('src/tests/java')
        }
    }
}
```