# Robolectric - AndroidStudio - Could not find method testCompile() for arguments

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, robolectric

I am trying to run some basic unit tests with Robolectric and AssertJ in AndroidStudio. I have added Robolectric, AssertJ, and JUnit into my `build.gradle` file with the `testCompile` method. However, when I try to actually run the unit tests I continue to get an error saying "Could not find method testCompile()".

I have tried replacing the `testCompile` methods with `androidTestCompile` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637608/specifying-test-dependencies-with-the-gradle-android-build-system), but then none of the Robolectric, AssertJ, and JUnit classes can be found to import in my `SampleTest.java` class.

Also I created a very basic sample app to see if I could get Robolectric working. Everything is working fine with that app which is confusing me, that project can be found [here](https://github.com/davidargylethacker/robolectric-sample/tree/develop).

Some help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Here is the log output:

```
Testing started at 4:45 PM ...
4:45:18 PM: Executing external tasks 'cleanTest test --tests com.master.SampleTest'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/Users/dthacker/Code/Repos/Default/CoreV2/a-fp-core/build.gradle' line: 45
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':a-fp-core'.
> Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2] on project ':a-fp-core'.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 2.163 secs
Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2] on project ':a-fp-core'.
```

Here is my test class:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricGradleTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void sampleTest() throws Exception {

        String testString = "hey";

        assertThat(testString).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

Here is the a-fp-core build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
       classpath "org._10ne.gradle:rest-gradle-plugin:0.3.2"
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: "org.10ne.rest"

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
   maven { url 'http://lorenzo.villani.me/android-cropimage/' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':a-fa-core-data')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'

    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
```

Folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]}

My tests in Android Studio:

[image: Unit Test]

Comment: I do not believe tests are working for Android Libraries + `Robolectric`. Can you show us the `build.gradl` for `a-fp-core`?

Comment: Really? So should we be using something like http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support instead?

Sorry @JaredBurrows, I wasn't clear. I included the `build.gradle` for `a-fp-core` already and edited my post to label it correctly.

Comment: well, [some people say](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/triumph-android-studio-1-2-sneaks-in-full-testing-support/) they should work together eventually, although getting robolectric to work in android is a big headache each time...

Comment: Ok I got confused. Your error says "a-fp-core". One thing I do not see is your "tests" folder. Since you just came from `Eclipse` to `AS`, you are having to override your `sourceSets`.  Please see or simply make your folders like a normal Android Studio project. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22511405/950427.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that makes sense. I modified the folder structure to what I assume is the expected way. I still get the same 'Could not find method testCompile()' error though.

Comment: Can you post a photo of your folder structure? And updated `build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes, I've updated it with my most recent attempt @JaredBurrows

Comment: Very good! Remove the `sourceSets`. Are you running from IDE? make sure you are the "beta" unit testing turned on. You will see the IDE recognize the  "testCompile" folder structure.

Comment: Oh so I can just remove sourceSets altogether and I don't need the androidTest.setRoot('tests') line?

It looks like this issue is solved now! Thanks for the help @JaredBurrows!

Comment: Can I post an answer?

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect.

Comment: @dthacker Alright, done. Let me know if you need help with your tests as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SourceSets:

I can tell you are coming from an *Eclipse-based* project based on your `sourceSets`:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
    }
}
```

I would suggest removing your `sourceSets` and using the Android Studio/Intellij project structure: `src/main, src/test`.

### Running `Unit` tests from the `IDE`:

Make sure you have "Unit Tests" turned on.

[image: Unit testing in Android Studio]

This allows you to run your unit tests in the IDE. Please following the instructions from the official Android documentation:

Source: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

### Running `Unit` tests from commandline:

`gradlew test`